# How to transform a sequential string of chess moves into a vertical dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe of chess games with two columns as shown below

```
dd <- data.frame(
  game_id = c(101,102),
  moves = c("1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nc6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Be3 Be7","1.e3 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 e5 6.Ndb5 d6")  
)
```

Here each row is a separate game uniquely identified by the game id. The moves column contain all the moves of a game in sequential order from left to right. The serial number of the move can be identified by the number just before each dot ".". Each move has two parts; the first part is always the move by the white player followed by the second part which is the  move by the black player. The two parts are separated by a single space. As shown in the above data, two consecutive moves are also separated by a single space, however, there is no gap between the dot of the serial number and the first character of the white player's move. The total number of moves in a game is arbitrary as some games end in a few moves while others may have many moves.

**Question**: As we can see all the moves of a game are present in one single cell of the dataframe which is not very easy for analysis. I want to convert this to a dataframe with a better structure as shown below:

```
game_id  | move_no | white | black
----------------------------------
    101  | 1       | e4    | c5
    101  | 2       | Nf3   | d6
    101  | 3       | d4    | cxd4
    101  | 4       | Nxd4  | Nf6
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: From experience, PGN files are messy, often have some spacing mistakes. Also recommend adding a use case where the game was resigned by black, i.e. missing last move

Answer (score 3):

We can splot the move string with a regular expression. Here I've used `stringr::str_match_all` to capture each part of the moves.

```
dd$moves |>
  stringr::str_match_all(r"{(\d+)\.(\S+) (\S+)}") |>
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(move_id=as.numeric(x[,2]), white=x[,3], black=x[,4])) |> 
  Map(cbind.data.frame, game_id=dd$game_id, m=_) |>
  do.call("rbind", args=_)
```

which will return

```
   game_id m.move_id m.white m.black
1      101         1      e4      c5
2      101         2     Nf3      d6
3      101         3      d4    cxd4
4      101         4    Nxd4     Nf6
5      101         5     Nc3     Nc6
6      101         6     Bc4      e6
7      101         7     Be3     Be7
8      102         1      e3      c5
9      102         2     Nf3     Nc6
```

The main part is the regular expression `r"{(\d+)\.(\S+) (\S+)}"` which finds a number followed by a period, then tries to find two non-space-containing piece names with a space between them.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I am getting an error with this in the last two lines as shown below.

> dd$moves |>
  +   stringr::str_match_all(r"{(\d+)\.(\S+) (\S+)}") |>
  +   lapply(function(x) data.frame(move_id=as.numeric(x[,2]), white=x[,3], black=x[,4])) |> 
  +   Map(cbind.data.frame, game_id=dd$game_id, m=_) |>
  Error: unexpected input in:
  "  lapply(function(x) data.frame(move_id=as.numeric(x[,2]), white=x[,3], black=x[,4])) |> 
  Map(cbind.data.frame, game_id=dd$game_id, m=_"
>   do.call("rbind", args=_)
Error: unexpected input in "  do.call("rbind", args=_"

Comment: What version of R are you running. I did you the latest pipe and placeholder syntax. If you have an older version that might be the issue.

Comment: Its R version 4.1.2, so I think it should be good, although the latest available version is 4.2.0

Comment: Yeah the `_` syntax came with 4.2. If you are already using `dplyr` or other tidyverse function you can use `%>%` rather than `|>` and `.` rather than `_`  and that should work in many more versions of R

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very inelegant answer using the stringr, dplyr, and tidyr libraries.

First we split the character vector of moves into data.frame per each move using str_split_fixed from stringr. Then we append these columns to the existing data.frame.

Next we reshape the data using dplyr and tidyr. First, we pivot the "move" columns from wide to long form data. Then we infer the color of the "move" by the order given above, as well as the number of the move by the number of movement columns.

Then we pivot the newly created movement data by color. From there, we modify the moves are recorded so that one "move" corresponds to one "turn" (aka a move of each color). Then we group by move number and game type, and do a small clean up from leftover null columns from our pivot.

Not the most elegant answer in the world but it works? Note you'll need to update the select and pivot_longer statements to reflect larger numbers of moves

```r
#load libs
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#create sample data
chess = data.frame(
  game_id = c(101,102),
  moves = c("1.e4 2Nf3 d6 Nf6","1.e3 2Nf4 nc6 cxd4")
)

#split characters vectors to columns
moves = data.frame(str_split_fixed(chess$moves," ",Inf)) #returns a matrix by default so coerce to data.frame to make binding easier
chess = bind_cols(chess,moves) #bind the new data

#melt the data into long form
chess %>%
  select(game_id,X1:X4) %>% #here we avoid selecting the default col we don't need, BUT- BE SURE to updated X1:X4 per length of moves
  pivot_longer(cols = X1:X4,names_to="move_no") %>% #melt/pivot split columns to one column
  mutate(color = rep(c("white","black"),ncol(chess)-2)) %>% #infer color by every other move, infer length by n of movement columns
  pivot_wider(names_from=color,values_from=value) %>% #pivot moves by color wider
  mutate(move_no = sort(rep(c(1:(ncol(chess)-2)),2))) %>% #update move_no colum to be accurate, note we use sort to get the needed order of moves
  group_by(game_id,move_no) %>% 
  summarise(
    white = last(na.omit(white)), #last will return the last non NA value, getting us to a valid data.frame
    black = last(na.omit(black))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work with small examples where there are only a few moves. But with an actual game it gives an error. Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `color`.
i `color = rep(c("white", "black"), ncol(chess) - 2)`.
i `color` must be size 4 or 1, not 184.

Comment: Got the above error "must be size 4 or 1, not 184" with this 30 move game "1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nc6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Be3 Be7 8.Qe2 a6 9.O-O-O Qc7 10.Bb3 O-O 11.g4 Nxd4 12.Rxd4 Nd7 13.g5 Nc5 14.e5 dxe5 15.Rh4 g6 16.Rg1 Bd7 17.Rg3 f5 18.gxf6 Bxf6 19.Rhg4 Nxb3+ 20.axb3 Bg7 21.Ne4 Bb5 22.c4 Be8 23.h4 Rf5 24.Rg1 a5 25.Ng5 Qe7 26.h5 a4 27.hxg6 hxg6 28.bxa4 Rxa4 29.Kb1 Qd6 30.c5 Qd5 31.Rxa4 Bxa4 32.f3 Bb3 33.Rc1 Qc6 34.Ne4 Bd5 35.Rd1 Bxe4+ 36.fxe4 Qxe4+ 37.Ka2 Bf6 38.Qd2 Rf3 39.Qd7 Qc4+ 40.Kb1 Rxe3 41.Qe8+ Kg7 42.Qd7+ Kh6 43.Qd2 Qe4+ 44.Ka1 g5 45.Qh2+ Kg6 46.Rh1 Re1+"

Comment: Hey there! You need to update the first two lines of the tidyr pipeline expression to reflect the larger number of columns, see below and note the changes in the select statement and pivot_longer statements

chess %>%
  select(game_id,X1:X92) %>% #here we avoid selecting the default col we don't need
  pivot_longer(cols = X1:X92,names_to="move_no"). That worked for me recreating with the text you added.

Answer (score 2):

with base **R**

**Data**

```r
x <- "
game_id  | moves
101      | 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nc6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Be3 Be7 
102      | 1.e3 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 e5 6.Ndb5 d6 
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(x) , header = T , sep = "|")
```

using `fn` function

```
fn <- function(df) {
  lst <- list()
  id <- 1 ; L <- 1
  clmn <- strsplit(trimws(df$moves) , "[. ]")
  for (i in clmn) {
    for (j in 1:(length(i) / 3)) {
      j <- 3*j - 2
      lst[[id]] <- c(df$game_id[[L]] , clmn[[L]][j:(j + 2)])
      id <- id + 1
    }
    L <- L + 1
  }
  lst
}
#===================================

df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind , fn(df)))
colnames(df) <- c("game_id" , "move_no" , "white" , "black")
```

**Output**

```
df
#>    game_id move_no white black
#> 1      101       1    e4    c5
#> 2      101       2   Nf3    d6
#> 3      101       3    d4  cxd4
#> 4      101       4  Nxd4   Nf6
#> 5      101       5   Nc3   Nc6
#> 6      101       6   Bc4    e6
#> 7      101       7   Be3   Be7
#> 8      102       1    e3    c5
#> 9      102       2   Nf3   Nc6
#> 10     102       3    d4  cxd4
#> 11     102       4  Nxd4   Nf6
#> 12     102       5   Nc3    e5
#> 13     102       6  Ndb5    d6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```r
dd <- tibble(
  game_id = c(101, 102),
  moves = c(
    "1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 Nc6 6.Bc4 e6 7.Be3 Be7",
    "1.e3 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 e5 6.Ndb5 d6"
  )
)

pattern <- r"{(\d+)\.(\S+) (\S+)}"
dd |>
  mutate(moves = str_extract_all(moves, pattern)) |>
  unnest(moves) |>
  mutate(
    move_no = str_replace(moves, pattern, "\\1"),
    white = str_replace(moves, pattern, "\\2"),
    black = str_replace(moves, pattern, "\\3")
  ) |>
  select(-moves)
```